# Replace text between specific words in sql server

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2008-r2, sql-server-2012

I got column with `nvarchar(max)` type. 
it has html text as string. like bellow.

```
<a>hi_this </a>
<i>is_sample</i>
<p>text_data</P>
<a>in_column</a>
<p>this_is_paragraph</p>
<a>this_is_end</a>
```

Is there anyway top replace underscore( `_` ) symbol between tags `<p>` and `</p>` with space

so I want final output like bellow.

```
<a>hi_this </a>
<i>is_sample</i>
<p>text data</P>
<a>in_column</a>
<p>this is paragraph</p>
<a>this_is_end</a>
```

is it possible?

**Update:**
it is in single row like this.
'< a >hi_this < /a >< i >is_sample< /i >< p >text data< /P >< a >in_column< /a >
< p >this is paragraph< /p > < a >this_is_end< /a >'

Comment: Markup in a database is a bad idea.

Comment: You have two problems: the "obvious" approach of regex requires usiung .NET code in SQL Server (supported, but extra steps); and second regex are not good at parsing HTML (like) content (HTML is not regular). If the HTML is sufficiently restricted in form a regex based approach may be viable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I really don't think SQL is the best tool for this, but I have done something that seems to work for your situation. The first step is to build a table of numbers. If you already have one then great, use that, but for the sake of a complete answer I have assumed you don't.

This is done by simply using a [table value constructor](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-GB/library/dd776382.aspx) to create a table of 10 rows (`N1`), then cross joining this with itself to get 100 rows (`N3`), then cross joining this with itself to get a table of 10,000 rows (`Numbers`) then using [`ROW_NUMBER()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186734.aspx) to get a number from 1-10,000 for each row:

```
WITH N1 AS (SELECT N FROM (VALUES (1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1)) t (N)),
N2 (N) AS (SELECT 1 FROM N1 AS N1 CROSS JOIN N1 AS N2),
Numbers (Number) AS (SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY N1.N) FROM N2 AS N1 CROSS JOIN N2 AS N2)

SELECT  *
FROM    Numbers;
```

Further reading on this, and other methods of doing this can be found in the series [Generate a set or sequence without loops](http://sqlperformance.com/2013/01/t-sql-queries/generate-a-set-1). If you need more than 10,000 numbers simply add more cross joins until you have enough

Once you have your numbers table, you can use [`SUBSTRING()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187748.aspx) to identify the position of all of your opening `<p>` tags, using `

```
DECLARE @S NVARCHAR(500) = '
    <a>hi_this </a>
    <i>is_sample</i>
    <p>text_data</P>
    <a>in_column</a>
    <p>this_is_paragraph</p>
    <a>this_is_end</a>';

WITH N1 AS (SELECT N FROM (VALUES (1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1)) t (N)),
N2 (N) AS (SELECT 1 FROM N1 AS N1 CROSS JOIN N1 AS N2),
Numbers (Number) AS (SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY N1.N) FROM N2 AS N1 CROSS JOIN N2 AS N2)

SELECT  OriginalString = SUBSTRING(@S, Number, CHARINDEX('</p>', @s, Number + 1) - Number + 4),
        Start = Number,
        NumChars = CHARINDEX('</p>', @s, Number + 1) - Number + 4,
        NewString = REPLACE(SUBSTRING(@S, Number, CHARINDEX('</p>', @s, Number + 1) - Number + 4), '_', ' ')
FROM    Numbers
WHERE   SUBSTRING(@S, Number, 3) = '<p>';
```

Result:

```
OriginalString              Start       NumChars    NewString
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
<p>text_data</P>            40          16          <p>text data</P>
<p>this_is_paragraph</p>    80          24          <p>this is paragraph</p>
```

Here you use `SUBSTRING(@S, Number, 3) = '<p>'` to get the starting position of each `p` tag, then you can use [`CHARINDEX()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186323.aspx) to get the position of the next closing `p` tag, and replace the text in between.

Finally you need to use the output from this to replace the original string, which you can do using [`STUFF()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188043.aspx):

```
DECLARE @S NVARCHAR(500) = '
    <a>hi_this </a>
    <i>is_sample</i>
    <p>text_data</P>
    <a>in_column</a>
    <p>this_is_paragraph</p>
    <a>this_is_end</a>';

WITH N1 AS (SELECT N FROM (VALUES (1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1)) t (N)),
N2 (N) AS (SELECT 1 FROM N1 AS N1 CROSS JOIN N1 AS N2),
Numbers (Number) AS (SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY N1.N) FROM N2 AS N1 CROSS JOIN N2 AS N2),
Data AS
(   SELECT  OriginalString = SUBSTRING(@S, Number, CHARINDEX('</p>', @s, Number + 1) - Number + 4),
            Start = Number,
            NumChars = CHARINDEX('</p>', @s, Number + 1) - Number + 4,
            NewString = REPLACE(SUBSTRING(@S, Number, CHARINDEX('</p>', @s, Number + 1) - Number + 4), '_', ' ')
    FROM    Numbers
    WHERE   SUBSTRING(@S, Number, 3) = '<p>'
)
SELECT  @S = STUFF(@S, Start, NumChars, NewString)
FROM    Data;

PRINT @S;
```

Which gives:

```
    <a>hi_this </a>
    <i>is_sample</i>
    <p>text data</P>
    <a>in_column</a>
    <p>this is paragraph</p>
    <a>this_is_end</a>
```

Answer (score 2):

Why not use a simple REPLACE funtion

```
update my_table
set path = replace(path, '_', ' ')
WHERE path like '<p>%'
```

Comment: Can you try this now?? 
Its seems to check out.

I am getting the expected results in my database

Answer (score 0):

You can use `REPLACE` with `CASE` in following:

```
SELECT CASE 
          WHEN col LIKE '<p>%' AND col LIKE '%</p>' THEN REPLACE(col, '_', ' ') 
          ELSE col 
       END AS col
FROM #table1
```

---

**OUTPUT**

```
<a>hi_this </a>
<i>is_sample</i>
<p>text data</P>
<a>in_column</a>
<p>this is paragraph</p>
<a>this_is_end</a>
```

[**SQL FIDDLE**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/e2b40/1)

---

**UPDATE**

As you want, this will combine result set to 1 row:

```
DECLARE @combine VARCHAR(MAX)

;WITH cte AS (
   SELECT CASE WHEN col LIKE '<p>%' and col LIKE '%</p>' THEN REPLACE(col, '_', ' ') ELSE col END AS col
   FROM table1
)
SELECT @combine = COALESCE(@combine, ' ') + col
FROM cte
SELECT @combine as col
```

---

**OUTPUT**

```
 <a>hi_this </a><i>is_sample</i><p>text data</P><a>in_column</a><p>this is paragraph</p><a>this_is_end</a>
```

**[SQL FIDDLE](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/e2b40/2)**

Comment: hi stanislovas. i need all the strings in single row. not in multiple rows.

Comment: This is what you provided in your question. `so I want final output like bellow.` It's equal as in my answer. What do you mean with `i need all the strings in single row. not in multiple rows`?

Comment: i have updated my question. have you understood now?

Comment: Updated my answer, check It out.